# Drawing a angle / arc, filled with a radiant in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Problem: Im drawing a spaceship on the canvas. Upon hovering over it's x/y, im drawing an arc on the canvas, indicating the starships weapons **angle and range** (considering the starships current Baring/facing). Currently the determined angle is being drawn in green and extends as far as the weapons range value allows.

However, i would like to use a gradiant to fill the determined arc to indicate a drop-off in accuracy (i.e. gradiant begins at green, moves to orange, turns red the further away from the starships Position the angle is).

However, i dont know how i could replace my stock ctx.fill() on the drawn arc with a gradiant.

```
var ship {
  loc: {x, y}, // lets say 100, 100
  facing: facing // lets say facing 0, i.e. straight right
  weapons: objects (range, startArc, endArc) // lets say 50, 300, 60 -> 120 degree angle, so -60 and +60 from facing (0/360)
}
        for (var i = 0; i < weapon.arc.length; i++){
            var p1 = getPointInDirection(weapon.range, weapon.arc[i][0] + angle, pos.x, pos.y);
            var p2 = getPointInDirection(weapon.range, weapon.arc[i][1] + angle, pos.x, pos.y)
            var dist = getDistance( {x: pos.x, y: pos.y}, p1);
            var rad1 = degreeToRadian(weapon.arc[i][0] + angle);
            var rad2 = degreeToRadian(weapon.arc[i][1] + angle);        

            fxCtx.beginPath();          
            fxCtx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
            fxCtx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);   
            fxCtx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, dist, rad1, rad2, false);
            fxCtx.closePath();
            fxCtx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
            fxCtx.fillStyle = "green";
            fxCtx.fill();
            fxCtx.globalAlpha = 1;
}
```

is it possible to replace the arc/globalalpha/fill so use a gradiant flow instead of it being colored fixed and if so, how ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill an arc with a gradient, animated just for the fun.

Uses a radial gradient and set colour stops as a fraction of distance.

The function createRadialGradient takes 6 numbers the position x,y and start radius and the position x,y and end radius of the gradient.

Colour stops are added via the gradient object addColorStop function that takes a value 0 inner to 1 outer part of the gradient and the colour as a CSS color string. "#F00" or "rgba(200,0,0,0.5)" or "RED"

Then just use the gradient as the fill style.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function update(time) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // position of zones in fractions
  var posRed = 0.8  + Math.sin(time / 100) * 0.091; 
  var posOrange = 0.5 + Math.sin(time / 200) * 0.2;
  var posGreen = 0.1 + Math.sin(time / 300) * 0.1;
  var pos = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2
  };

  var dist = 100;
  var ang1 = 2 + Math.sin(time / 1000) * 0.5;
  var ang2 = 4 + Math.sin(time / 1300) * 0.5;
  var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(pos.x, pos.y, 0, pos.x, pos.y, dist);
  grad.addColorStop(0, "#0A0");
  grad.addColorStop(posGreen, "#0A0");
  grad.addColorStop(posOrange, "#F80");
  grad.addColorStop(posRed, "#F00");
  grad.addColorStop(1, "#000");

  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
  ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, dist, ang1, ang2);
  ctx.fill();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```